# Drupal 7 with Multiple Login sources?

Tags: drupal, authentication, module

I'm just a new to Drupal but i wanna make my site to be authenticated from external login sources. I mean, not to use the current Drupal database to login. Then use one or more external databases.

To make it a little more clear:

- User Login Authentication will not use the existing Drupal database.
- Then it will use the external database(s)
- External Database will be one or more (If User is not found on one external database, then found on another source again.)

I've been trying to hack the Drupal Login but i can't make it yet as the structure is complicated enough. Any solution or suggestion please?

- Which files will be needed to modify?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't completely discard Drupal's user system for this, but rather piggy tail on it with your own authentication. The way this works is by 1) collecting user credentials, 2) authenticating against your custom sources and 3) registering/logging in an external user.

### Collecting credentials

One way of collecting user credentials is by hijacking the user login form. You do this by implementing [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add your own validation callback.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['#validate'][] = array('mymodule_user_login_validate');
    $form['#validate'][] = array('mymodule_user_login_submit');
  }
}
```

The login form will look exactly the same and but it will send the username and password to your callback instead.

The `user_login_name_validate()` and `user_login_final_validate()` callbacks are user.module's [default validators](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_default_validators/7). They supply user blocking functionality and brute force protection but feel free to leave them out.

### Authentication

When the login form is sent you pick up the credentials and authenticate against your custom sources.

```
function mymodule_user_login_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  mymodule_authenticate(
    $form_state['values']['name'],
    $form_state['values']['name']
  );
}
```

If the credentials doesn't check out you can just call [`form_set_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) to inform the user of what went wrong. Doing this will also make sure no further validation or submit callbacks are executed.

### External users

So if no error is evoked then Drupal will move on to running your submit callback. Then we can run [`user_external_login_register()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7) to create our external user as a Drupal user.

```
function mymodule_user_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  user_external_login_register($form_state['values']['name'], 'mymodule');
}
```

As the name implies, this function will also log the user in. And that should be it!

### There's a module for that

Chances are there is already a module for what you want to do. Always go search for [existing contrib modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules) before starting your own!

Answer (score 2):

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT',  'full/path/to/drupal');
$drupal_url  = 'http://site.com';
drupal_external_load($drupal_path, $drupal_url);

if ( !($user->uid > 0) ) {
  drupal_external_login('user', 'pass');  
} else {
  print 'user is already logged';
}

function drupal_external_load($drupal_url) {

  global $base_url;

  // set drupal base_url (if not set set in settings.php)
  // because it's used in session name
  $base_url = $drupal_url;

  // save current path
  $current_path = getcwd();

  // move to drupal path, because it uses relative path for its includes    
  chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);

  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

  // to use the drupal global user var (instead of session hack)
  // drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
  // return the current path
  chdir($current_path);
}

// load a drupal user into the user obj
function drupal_external_userload($user_info = array()) {

  // Dynamically compose a SQL query:
  $query = array();
  $params = array();

  if (is_numeric($user_info)) {

    $user_info = array('uid' => $user_info);
  }
  elseif (!is_array($user_info)) {

    return FALSE;
  }

  foreach ($user_info as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == 'uid' || $key == 'status') {

      $query[] = "$key = %d";
      $params[] = $value;
    }
    else if ($key == 'pass') {

      $query[] = "pass = '%s'";
      $params[] = md5($value);
    }
    else {

      $query[]= "LOWER($key) = LOWER('%s')";
      $params[] = $value;
    }
  }

  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {users} u WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $query), $params);

  if ($user = db_fetch_object($result)) {

    $user = drupal_unpack($user);
    $user->roles = array();

    if ($user->uid) {

      $user->roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID] = 'authenticated user';
    }
    else {

      $user->roles[DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID] = 'anonymous user';
    }

    $result = db_query('SELECT r.rid, r.name FROM {role} r INNER JOIN {users_roles} ur ON 

ur.rid = r.rid WHERE ur.uid = %d', $user->uid);

    while ($role = db_fetch_object($result)) {

      $user->roles[$role->rid] = $role->name;
    }

    //user_module_invoke('load', $user_info, $user);
  }
  else {

    $user = FALSE;
  }
  return $user;
}

// don't send any headers before calling this
function drupal_external_login($username, $password) {

  global $user;

  if ( $user->uid > 0 ) {

    if ( $user->name != $username ) {

      drupal_external_logout();

    } else {

      return true;
    }
  }

  require DRUPAL_ROOT. '/includes/password.inc' ;

  $account = user_load_by_name($username);

  if ( user_check_password($password, $account) ) {

    $user = $account;
    drupal_session_regenerate();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function drupal_external_logout() {

  global $user;
  session_destroy();
  $user = drupal_anonymous_user();
}
```